# GRAILS named query with to_char

Tags: grails

I am looking to query the matching records based on input number(say 56). The type of the column in ORACLE DB is Long. Expecting all matching records has the numbers for ex - 156, 567, 12356..etc. 
Is it possible to write a named query in GRAILS for above ?. Is there any other way out ?

Comment: What do you mean by `GRAILS named query with to_char` ? If you have the id you can do DomainName.get(id) and grab that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use database functions in your named queries, you can use the `sqlRestriction` clause. Note that the syntax must match you table and not domain class, so considering:

```
class MyDomain {
  Date myField
}
```

Your restriction can be:

```
def namedQueries = {
  someQuery {
    sqlRestriction("to_char(my_field, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '25/07/2013'")
  }
}
```